# which method does child class calls if it extends two classes with same method name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 classes -say A and B as parent to 1 class -child class and both classes A and B has a method myMethod.
Now if I call mymethod in child class which one does it refer to ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It calls whichever appears first in the Method Resolution Order (MRO), which depends on the order in which the subclass inheritance is defined:

```
>>> class A(object):
    def method(self):
        print('A.method')


>>> class B(object):
    def method(self):
        print('B.method')


>>> class C(A, B):
          # ^ A appears first in definition
    pass

>>> C.mro()
[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>]
                     # ^ and therefore is first in the MRO
>>> C().method()
A.method  # so that's what gets called
```

---

To ensure that *all* implementations of the method get called, you can use `super`, which will get the next implementation *"up"* the MRO:

```
>>> class A(object):
    def method(self):
        print('A.method')
        super(A, self).method()  # this will be resolved to B.method for C


>>> class B(object):
    def method(self):
        print('B.method')


>>> class C(A, B):
    pass

>>> C.mro()  # same as before
[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>]
>>> C().method()
A.method
B.method
```

Note that you do have to be a little careful doing this where you have multiple inheritance, as adding `super` to `B.method` would attempt to call `object.method`, which *isn't* implemented.

Comment: Thanks ... Also if you can tell that in case it calls A and then I want to access the method in B how will I call myMethod in B then???

Comment: Can you redefine the MRO explicitly?

Comment: In python3 you can use `super().method()`, in old python it's not that straight forward.

Comment: @skyking in Python 2 you can explicitly call method of A or B from C, ignoring mro. For instance in a method of C you can do `A.method(self)`

Comment: @ ElmoVanKielmo Yes, but my comment was intended to answer to  Shruti Srivastava's comment (but I may hav misunderstood it). It's if you want to delegate to the next class in `mro` that is not so straight forward in python2.

Comment: @ShrutiSrivastava I've added an example to demonstrate how you'd do this

Answer (score 0):

It will call A. I believe it uses whatever is first in the hierarchy, but I'm not completely familiar with the model of Python. I just tested it with this small sample though:

```
class A():
    def myMethod(self):
        print("This is A!")

class B():
    def myMethod(self):
        print("This is B!")

class child(A,B):
    def test(self):
        self.myMethod()

test = child()
test.test()
```